# Is there a specific library type called a Help Library in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013

I'm working on making custom help files for my SharePoint site and found an article that works through the process; however the first thing is to create a Help Library and I am not finding anything that states there is a specific type of library called Help Library. Before I create a generic library labeled help I just wanted to see if there was a specific library for this or if it's just a generic library used for the purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The help library is created by a site collection feature.
For SharePoint to create a Site Collection Help Library, you must first turn on the Custom Site Collection Help feature on the Site Collection Features page.

To turn on the Custom Site Collection Help feature:

1.On the Site Actions menu, click Site Settings.

2.Under Site Collection Administration, click Site Collection Features. The Site Collection Features page opens.

3.For the Custom Site Collection Help option, click Activate.

When you turn on Custom Site Collection Help, SharePoint creates a new library in the top-level site of the site collection. The new library is called Site Collection Help.

Hope this helps. Reference [Link](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Add-custom-help-to-a-site-collection-fa9faf46-9cb1-4804-a890-4f17ec01910f)